# Problem with DKMS upgrading 12.04 to kernel 3.6.9

Tags: ati, kernel, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 to Linux Kernel 3.6.9 as described [here](http://www.itworld.com/software/326691/upgrade-ubuntu-1210-or-1204-linux-kernel-369). This is what I get in console:

```
andres@andres-nt:/tmp$ sudo sh linux-kernel-3.6.9

    ########### This bash script is created by UpUbuntu.com ###########


    ########### Kernel 3.6.9 will be installed in an x86_64 system ###########

Press Enter to continue, or abort by pressing CTRL+C


--2013-01-13 01:12:10--  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.9-raring/linux-headers-3.6.9-030609_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_all.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12003176 (11M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: `linux-headers-3.6.9-030609_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_all.deb'

100%[======================================>] 12.003.176  88,4K/s   in 2m 20s  

2013-01-13 01:14:31 (84,0 KB/s) - `linux-headers-3.6.9-030609_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_all.deb' saved [12003176/12003176]

--2013-01-13 01:14:31--  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.9-raring/linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 951720 (929K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: `linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb'

100%[======================================>] 951.720      117K/s   in 9,5s    

2013-01-13 01:14:42 (97,6 KB/s) - `linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb' saved [951720/951720]

--2013-01-13 01:14:42--  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.9-raring/linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12418742 (12M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: `linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb'

100%[======================================>] 12.418.742   130K/s   in 1m 49s  

2013-01-13 01:16:32 (112 KB/s) - `linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb' saved [12418742/12418742]

--2013-01-13 01:16:32--  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.9-raring/linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb
Resolving kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.94.216
Connecting to kernel.ubuntu.com (kernel.ubuntu.com)|91.189.94.216|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 28401200 (27M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: `linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb'

100%[======================================>] 28.401.200   238K/s   in 4m 51s  

2013-01-13 01:21:24 (95,2 KB/s) - `linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb' saved [28401200/28401200]

Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic.
(Reading database ... 363604 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic (from linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.6.9-030609.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.6.9-030609 (from linux-headers-3.6.9-030609_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic (from linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic (from linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic_3.6.9-030609.201212031610_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.6.9-030609 (3.6.9-030609.201212031610) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.6.9-030609-generic (3.6.9-030609.201212031610) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.6.9-030609-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.6.9-030609-generic (3.6.9-030609.201212031610) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.6.9-030609-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168g-1.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw for module r8169
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
Setting up linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic (3.6.9-030609.201212031610) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.6.9-030609-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.6.9-030609-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log for more information.
```

And here is /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-8.961 for kernel 3.6.9-030609-generic (x86_64)
dom ene 13 01:23:17 ART 2013
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/3.6.9-030609-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘KCL_MEM_AllocLinearAddrInterval’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:2122:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘do_mmap’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:2122:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘kasInitExecutionLevels’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: error: ‘cpu_possible_map’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:4157:5: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.961/build/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.6.9-030609-generic'
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

I have an HP g4-1387la with an Core I5 with hybrid graphics card. Any advice ? I am using Catalyst driver as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/) so I don't know what is the problem with fglrx driver.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

1. Install the new kernel (It doesn't boot, I can't even acces with Ctrl+Alt+F1, all I get is a huge log).
2. Boot Ubuntu with the previous kernel selecting in Grub to boot with Previous Linux Version.
3. Install again ATI Catalyst but a newer version that works with 3.6.9 kernel (Catalyst 12.10) downloaded from ATI website. The installer will build the driver for both kernels.
4. Run `sudo aticonfig --initial -f` then`sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu` the `sudo reboot` and boot with the new kernel it should boot correctly.
5. To enable Direct Rendering for integrated card follow the instructions described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/) so you can boot with Integrated Intel Card.